# Angular Rest API with android

Tags: android, angularjs

I am able to call all the web services from Android however node server is not able to identify my session. I guess I have to pass the token for authentication while calling the web service from Android. I am using following code to login :

```
HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost("https://xyz/signIn");     
HttpResponse response = MainActivity.httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

At node server Express session management is used.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the token in the header of the request:

```
httpget.addHeader("Authorization", new StringBuilder("Bearer ").append(accessToken).toString());
```